# Modding a robosapien

Tags: diagram, layout

Has anyone got a diagram of the layout of the Robosapien v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest starting with [Robosapien V2 Hacks](http://www.evosapien.com/robosapien-hack/nocturnal/RoboSapienV2/), which includes a number of documented mods, along with documentation of all of the parts and connections that make up a Robosapien.  I also found a site with good photos of a [Robosapien dissection](http://www.markcra.com/robot/hackrobos.php).